# value of enum members, when some members have user-defined values

Tags: c++, enums

```
enum ABC{
 A,
 B,
 C=5,
 D,
 E
};
```

Are D and E guaranteed to be greater than 5 ?
Are A and B guaranteed to be smaller than 5 (if possible)?

**edit**: What would happen if i say `C=1`

Comment: If C=1 you will get 0, 1, 1, 2, 3. Check the rule in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is guaranteed by C++ Standard 7.2/1:

> The identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are
>   required. An enumerator-definition with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the
>   constant-expression. The constant-expression shall be of integral or enumeration type. If the first
>   enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An enumerator-definition
>   without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous
>   enumerator by one.

Comment: Thus here A: 0, B: 1, C: 5, D: 6, E: 7.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, yes (see Kirill's answer).  However, beware the [following situation](http://codepad.org/5GB1IZ4D):

```
enum ABC
{ 
  A,
  B,
  C = 5,
  D,
  E,
  F = 4,
  G,
  H
};
```

The compiler will not avoid collisions with previously used values, nor will it try to make each value greater than all previous values.
In this case, G will be greater than F, but not C, D, or E.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is guaranteed and the value of A and B has to be 0 and 1 respectively.